# Named backreferences with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, backreference

Pretty straightforward; I can't seem to find anything definitive regarding PHP's `preg_replace()` supporting named backreferences:

```
// should match, replace, and output: user/profile/foo
$string = 'user/foo';
echo preg_replace('#^user/(?P<id>[^/]+)$#Di', 'user/profile/(?P=id)', $string);
```

This is a trivial example, but I'm wondering if this syntax, `(?P=name)` is simply not supported. Syntactical issue, or non-existent functionality?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They exist:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php

With preg_replace_callback:

```
function my_replace($matches) {
    return '/user/profile/' . $matches['id'];
}
$newandimproved = preg_replace_callback('#^user/(?P<id>[^/]+)$#Di', 'my_replace', $string);
```

Or even quicker

```
$newandimproved = preg_replace('#^user/([^/]+)$#Di', '/user/profile/$1', $string);
```

Comment: **Thanks Dimitry;** If the answer is *not supported*, then I'll simply revert to numbered references.

Comment: You can use named matches with preg_replace_callback.

Comment: Ah, from the array argument... Good to know, however doesn't suit the purpose here. Damn, what a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 7):

`preg_replace` does not support named backreferences.

`preg_replace_callback` supports named backreferences, but after PHP 5.3, so expect it to fail on PHP 5.2 and below.

Comment: "Back references to the named subpatterns can be achieved by (?P=name) or, since PHP 5.2.2, also by \k<name> or \k'name'. Additionally PHP 5.2.4 added support for \k{name} and \g{name}." This quote (from Dimitry's provided link) applies to `preg_match()` and `preg_match_all()` only, correct?

Comment: Yes, it only applies to the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`preg_replace` does not supported named subpatterns yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
class oreg_replace_helper {
    const REGEXP = '~
(?<!\x5C)(\x5C\x5C)*+
(?:
    (?:
        \x5C(?P<num>\d++)
    )
    |
    (?:
        \$\+?{(?P<name1>\w++)}
    )
    |
    (?:
        \x5Cg\<(?P<name2>\w++)\>
    )
)?
~xs';

    protected $replace;
    protected $matches;

    public function __construct($replace) {
        $this->replace = $replace;
    }

    public function replace($matches) {
        var_dump($matches);
        $this->matches = $matches;
        return preg_replace_callback(self::REGEXP, array($this, 'map'), $this->replace);
    }

    public function map($matches) {
        foreach (array('num', 'name1', 'name2') as $name) {
            if (isset($this->matches[$matches[$name]])) {
                return stripslashes($matches[1]) . $this->matches[$matches[$name]];
            }
        }
        return stripslashes($matches[1]);
    }
}

function oreg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject) {
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, array(new oreg_replace_helper($replace), 'replace'), $subject);
}
```

then you can use either `\g<name> ${name} or $+{name}` as reference in your replace statement.

cf (http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#namedcapture)