# PHP - preg_replace backreferencing

Tags: php, preg-replace, backreference

I have big problems understanding how to use `preg_replace` with backreferencing.

I have a plain-text string and want to replace every link with the HTML syntax for a link. So "www.mydomain.tld" or "http://www.mydomain.tld" or "http://mydomain.tld" should be wrapped in an HTML a-tag. I have found a working function that does this online, but I want to understand how to do it myself.

In the function I found, this is the replacement:

```
"\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow\">\\2</a>"
```

I see some escaped quotation marks in there and these bits: `\\1` `\\2`.
According to the PHP documentation these are backreferences. But how do I use them, what do they do?

I found nothing about that in the spec, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you see this http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php or http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html?

Comment: These aren't backreferences. In this context they are match group placeholders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job for you. Please see below for an explanation on how it all works.

```
$string = 'some text www.example.com more text http://example.com more text https://www.example.com more text';

$string = preg_replace('#\b(?:http(s?)://)?((?:[a-z\d-]+\.)+[a-z]+)\b#', "<a href='http$1://$2'>http$1://$2</a>", $string);

echo $string; // some text <a href='http://www.example.com'>http://www.example.com</a> more text <a href='http://example.com'>http://example.com</a> more text <a href='https://www.example.com'>https://www.example.com</a> more text
```

`\b` match word boundary
`(?:http(s?)://)?` optionally match string if it contains `'http://'` or `'https://'`, if https grab the `'s'` so we can build correct URL

`(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)+` match one or more occurrence of of series of letter/numbers followed by a period

`[a-z]+` match one ore more occurrences of a series of letters, TLD, note TLDs are now open for purchase so can't limit length anymore. see http://tinyurl.com/cle6jqb

We then capture both of the last two sections in addition to the `'s'` in a backreference by enclosing them in parentheses.

We then build the URL:

```
<a href='http$1://$2'>http$1://$2</a>
```

`http$1://` create HTTP if HTTPS the backreference `$1` will contain an `'s'`

`$2` will contain the domain name. We make the link where the URL is made the link text.

Comment: How can you escape in `$1333$2` the number 333 the number in between the two backreferences?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something similar to this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/ ', "<a href=\"$1\">Link</a>", $yourtext);
```

Some usefull links:
Try Regex with this tool: [click](http://rubular.com/r/QufgP3gXPg)
Regex from: [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/)
Named backreferences: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255149/named-backreferences-with-preg-replace)