# Capture everything enclosed by parenthesis

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex that captures successfully the following bolded text:

> background-image: url(
>   **https://domain/adress/with/other/stuff?alsoaquerystring=whynot** );

Expected output is:

> https://domain/adress/with/other/stuff?alsoaquerystring=whynot

And this is what I have tried so far, but I can't manage to say "capture everything that's inside here, no matter what characters it has got".

```
/background-image: url\((?P<image>)+\)/;
```

It needs to be compatible with PHP `preg_replace()`.

Comment: Use `background-image: url\((?P<image>[^)]+)\)`. What is the expected output?

Comment: Added the expected output.

Comment: I do not think you need a named capturing group, just use a numbered one (in PHP `preg_replace`, you can't use named backreferences in the *string* replacement pattern). See http://ideone.com/lHqXFZ.

Comment: I know, but is there a reason for which I should NOT use a named capture group? I mean, is it heavier on a performance point-of-view, or it is just useless but nothing bad actually happens? And I have already used named capturing groups with `preg_match()`!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255149/named-backreferences-with-preg-replace. You may still keep them, but in the replacement pattern, use corresponding numbered backreferences.

Comment: Maybe it does work only with `preg_match()` but not with `preg_replace()`?

Comment: They work, but you cannot reference them by name from the string replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
background-image: url\((.*?)\);
```

By using `( )` you are creating a capture group in regex.

See https://regex101.com/r/VNsTPU/1/ as an example. It's a very basic example, you can improve to strip out white space between parentheses or just trim after you are done.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386562/php-capture-group) about using capture groups with PHP, if you are unfamiliar.

**Update**: If you are trying to do it with `preg_replace` this is how you would do it:

```
$regex = = 'background-image: url\((.*?)\);';
$var = 'background-image: url( https://domain/adress/with/other/stuff?alsoaquerystring=whynot )';
preg_replace($regex,'$1',$var);
```